# Elasticsearch - check which all fields are indexed in an index?

Tags: elasticsearch

I browse to `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/<index_name>/_mappings` and it returns the fields in an index.

This is one of the field.

```
{"dob" : { "type": "string", "analyzer" : "my_custom_analyzer"}}
```

With above response, does this mean DOB field is by default **indexed**? or `index: true` has to be explicitly there for this field to be indexed?

Comment: which version of Elasticsearch you are using ? because `string` type is now deprecated .

Comment: ElasticSearch 2.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're using a very old version of Elasticsearch, likely 2.x or earlier.

However, based on the mapping you've shared, `string` fields are [indexed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/mapping-index.html) [by default](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/string.html), in your case, `dob` is analyzed by a custom analyzer called `my_custom_analyzer` and the resulting tokens will be indexed automatically.

Comment: A field being analyzed = A field being indexed?

Comment: are these 2 terms interchangeable?

Comment: No, but it makes no sense to analyze something that won't be indexed. Analysis is the process of slice and dicing the text value into tokens. Indexing is the process of adding those analyzed tokens into the inverted index. You can also index tokens that are not analyzed (what is called `keyword` in the newer versions or `index: not_analyzed` in your version)